# gnuplot changing format of calculated variable

Tags: function, variables, plot, format, gnuplot

I have this code in gnuplot to plot the mean.

The problem is that the value is very low like 0.00000000000000001.
I woul like to plot it in scientific notation, but i have this error if i try to follow the set format guide.

Thank you!
Code that I have:

```
stats filename u ($1*$2):2 nooutput
mean = STATS_sum_x/STATS_sum_y
set arrow 1 from mean, graph 0 to mean, graph 1 nohead lw 2 lc rgb "red" front
set label 1 sprintf("Mean: %8.6f", mean) at mean, graph 1 offset 1,-0.7
```

Code if I try to have scientific notation:

```
stats filename u ($1*$2):2 nooutput
mean = STATS_sum_x/STATS_sum_y
set arrow 1 from mean, graph 0 to mean, graph 1 nohead lw 2 lc rgb "red" front
set label 1 sprintf("Mean: %s*10^{%S}", mean) at mean, graph 1 offset 1,-0.7
```

Error:

```
f_sprintf: attempt to print numeric value with string format
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also a bit confused about the documentation for `help format_specifiers`.

Check `help gprintf` and try using `gprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`. Maybe the following is using `%h` is also fine for you.

**Code:**

```
reset session
mean = 0.00000000000000001    # or 1e-17
set label 1 gprintf("Mean: %h", mean)
plot x
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It solved my problem ! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

@theozh gave you the correct answer, I'd just like to expand a bit on that. If you want to enhance the appearance of the label, you might want to replace the x with a × and the hyphen with a proper minus sign. Then you can create your own custom label with by using `%t` and `%T`:

```
set encoding utf8
set minussign
a=1e-17
set label 1 gprintf("Mean: %.0t × 10^{%T}", a)
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

If you plan on using LaTeX you might of course as well use LaTeX code instead.

Answer (score 1):

I did not know about the Gnuplot's `gprintf` function, but I was around with the birth of C ... and the `[s]printf` functions.  I believe the original post was confusing the formats between the two.  `sprintf("Mean: %s*10^{%S}", mean)` has a few sprintf errors:

- `%s`  formats a string and mean is a number
- `%S`  unknown `sprintf` format and missing argument
- `sprintf` will assume an argument for each formatting specifier.

Here is a Gnuplot script with some examples of `sprintf` formats for floating point numbers:

```
a=1.2345e-17
b=5.4321
print sprintf("a=%f", a)
print sprintf("a=%e", a)
print sprintf("a=%g", a)
print sprintf("a=%.3e", a)
print sprintf("a=%.3g", a)
print sprintf("b=%f", b)
print sprintf("b=%e", b)
print sprintf("b=%g", b)
print sprintf("b=%.3e", b)
print sprintf("b=%.3g", b)
print sprintf("Multiple arguments: a=%g  b=%f", a, b)"
```

and the results:

```
a=0.000000
a=1.234500e-17
a=1.2345e-17
a=1.235e-17
a=1.23e-17
b=5.432100
b=5.432100e+00
b=5.4321
b=5.432e+00
b=5.43
Multiple arguments: a=1.2345e-17  b=5.432100
```

The `gprintf` function is a nice option, and `help format specifiers` pertains to that function.  For `sprintf` specifiers search the internet for C function help.